# How to change format of date using sqlplus

Tags: linux, bash, sqlplus

i have problem with sqlplus couse

sqldeveloper gives me data like this:

```
22/03/09 52345
22/03/10 53462
22/03/11 26436
```

and sqlplus gives me data in this format

```
09-MAR-22 52345
10-MAR-22 53462
11-MAR-22 26436
```

Is any way to change name of month on number using an argument or set ... ?

LIKE:
sqlplus [arg] Login/pass@key << EOD

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to set the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html#GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F) session variable:

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

This will only work for dates. There are other settings for timestamps  ([NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.html#GUID-1070C91E-6C9D-4FAF-BD58-7880DBED9899)) and timestamps with timezones ([NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT.html#GUID-A340C735-BA5A-4704-B24C-AC2C2380BA9E)).

You can also set these variables as environment variables, and `sqlplus` should pick them up. You can also set these defaults in SQL Developer by going to Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS.

Check the Oracle documentation for more information.